# The statement of the mean value theorem used in lemma 3 on pg.111 in Royden 4th edition.

Tags: real-analysis, calculus, analysis, measure-theory, proof-writing

This the ordinary statement of the mean value theorem that I already know:

> [image]

This is lemma 3, and before it the version of the MVT that this lemma is similar to:

> [image]

My question is:

1-How is the version of the mean value theorem I already knew in picture one is similar to the one from which lemma 3 originated?

Could anyone help me in understanding this please?

Comment: Take $\frac{1}{b-a}$ to the other side in the version you know. Use the fact that $\alpha\leq f'(c)$ for any $c$ in the relevant interval, to rewrite $f'(c)(b-a)=f(b)-f(a)$ as $\alpha(b-a)\leq f(b)-f(a)$.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

According to the MVT you already know, we know that there exists $r$ on $(c,d)$ such that $f'(r)(d-c) = f(d)-f(c)$. But since $\alpha \leq f'(r)$, then $\alpha(d-c) \leq f'(r)(d-c) = f(d)-f(c)$ which the MVT applied in Royden.

Answer (score 1):

Say that $f$ is continuous on $[c,d]$ and differentiable on $(c,d)$, then by the MVT 
(that you know) there is a $e\in (c,d)$ such that 
$$
f'(e) = \frac{f(d) - f(c)}{d-c}
$$
So
$$
(d-c)f'(e) = f(d) - f(c).
$$
Now, assuming that $f'\geq \alpha$ on the interval $(c,d)$ we have
$$
(d-c)\alpha \leq (d-c)f'(e) = f(d) - f(c).
$$